# Add block from custom module to product blocks in loop?

Tags: magento2, product, blocks

When you search and many products are returned, each has a buy button - how would I add another button to each from a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

In your module, create `view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Your_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then copy the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` to your module under `view/frontend/templates/product/`.

You can then insert your button into this template file wherever you see fit.

Comment: This would be incompatible with another module,. You're only changing the template, it's the same as overwriting.

Comment: If I wanted to add another button from another module, this would stop working.

Comment: I could make a solution where additional buttons could be added from other modules via layout XML but you would still need to override the template. Would that be acceptable? Out of curiosity, what do you want these buttons to do?

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a way to do this without overwriting the template. I want it to work without other modules having to know mine exists and how it works.

Sorry, I'll settle for overwriting the template but it isn't at all what I was hoping for.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I can think of to do it without overriding the template would be to include some JS that inserts the button into each listing when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can try "Plugin" into the block `search_result_list` and in `toHTML` function you can append your html.